# Sed command with complex pattern and replacement

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the following two strings saved as variables:

```
str1='ds-cfg-global-aci: (targetcontrol="2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.17 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.19 || 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.10.2 || 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.16 || 2.16.840.1.113894.1.8.31") (version 3.0; acl "Anonymous control access"; allow(read) userdn="ldap:///anyone";)'

str2='ds-cfg-global-aci: (targetcontrol="2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.17 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.19 || 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.10.2 || 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.16 || 2.16.840.1.113894.1.8.31 || 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319 ") (version 3.0; acl "Anonymous control access"; allow(read) userdn="ldap:///anyone";)'
```

I want to replace 'str1' with 'str2' in a script using shell scripting.Can someone please help me out? I'm trying with `sed`, but I'm unable to do it.

I have tried using the following command :

```
sed -i 's_ ( ds-cfg-global-aci: \(targetcontrol="2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.17 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.19 || 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.10.2 || 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.16 || )2.16.840.1.113894.1.8.31( "\) \(version 3.0 ; acl "Anonymous control access" ; allow\(read\) userdn="ldap:///anyone" ; \) ) _\12.16.840.1.113894.1.8.31 || 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319\2_' 2.xml
```

It doesn't throw any errors,but it doesn't yield the expected output.The filecontents of '2.xml' is just the pattern.

Comment: all that's changing is adding `|| 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319 ")`? `sed 's/2.16.840.1.113894.1.8.31/& || 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319")/'`

Comment: Following command : sed -i 's/2.16.840.1.113894.1.8.31/& || 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319/' worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do with that `sed` command,. You seem to be trying to capture some groups but then don't use them. Anyway, what you want is something like:

```
sed -i "s#$str1#$str2#" file
```

Or, if you don't have the strings saved as variables:

```
sed -i 's#ds-cfg-global-aci: (targetcontrol="2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.17 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.19 || 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.10.2 || 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.16 || 2.16.840.1.113894.1.8.31") (version 3.0; acl "Anonymous control access"; allow(read) userdn="ldap:///anyone";)#ds-cfg-global-aci: (targetcontrol="2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.17 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.19 || 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.10.2 || 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1 || 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.16 || 2.16.840.1.113894.1.8.31 || 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319 ") (version 3.0; acl "Anonymous control access"; allow(read) userdn="ldap:///anyone";)#' file
```

Or, since the only difference seems to be that str1 doesn't contain `|| 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319`, just add that:

```
sed -i 's/")/ || 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319 ")/' file
```